# How I can close a excel windows automatic?

Tags: c#, cell, worksheet, excel

I want to open and change a cell in excel by using C#

And it works but if i save the document I get a windows from excel -.- and everytime i must click on the button. See the picture.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
                         {
                             MSExcel.Workbook book1 = null;
                             MSExcel.Worksheet sheet1;
                             MSExcel.Range range_A1;

                             try
                             {
                                 book1 = app.Workbooks.Open(file);
                                 sheet1 = (MSExcel.Worksheet)book1.Worksheets[1];
                                 range_A1 = sheet1.GetRange(cell);

                                 string content = range_A1.Value2.ToString();

                                 if (content == value || content == value2)
                                 {

                                     range_A1.Value2 = string.Empty;
                                     book1.Save(); // here i save the value
                                     Console.WriteLine(count +" - OPEN AND CHANGE - " + file + " SAVE");
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {

                                     Console.WriteLine(count + " - OPEN - " + file + " NOT SAVE");
                                 }

                                 count++;
                             }
                             catch (Exception)
                             {
                                 count++;
                                 Console.WriteLine(count + " - ERROR FILE " + file);
                                 liste.Add(file); 
                             }
                             finally
                             {
                                 book1.Close(false);

                             }

                         }
```

[image]

How I can make it automatic ?

Comment: take a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/83199/cannot-get-out-of-compatibility-mode-in-excel-2007), i think this can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Maybe also these two for additional hiding (if needed):

```
app.Visible = false;
app.ScreenUpdating = false;
```

Comment: the object app don't hae this methods

Comment: Isn't app of type [`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.displayalerts.aspx)?

Comment: no i use Tcks.MSOFFICE.Excel http://msofficefornet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20MS%20Office%20Wrapper%20for%20.NET

Comment: @Tarasov: Sorry, don't know, ask the creator of the lib.